# Popup Window won't work but no error is shown (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently working on a page that has a login layout with a create account window, login window, and forgot password window.

The problem I am having comes from the forgot window. You can see below that this is how I wanted the popup window to appear on the page.

```
class ForgotWindow(Screen):
    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)

   def VerificationBtn(self):
       if self.namee.text != "" and self.email.text != "":
           emailsent()
```

This is how I want the popup window to appear, and I did declare it as you can see below:

```
def emailsent():
    popup = Popup(title='Email Sent',
                  content=Label(text='Check your email for the verification code'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    popup.open()
```

However, whenever I press the button that is meant to show the popup window, it doesn't do anything and no errors appear on my code either so I can't seem to find the problem.

Can someone pleas help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Put a `print()` statement in your `emailsent()` method to see if it is actually being called.

Comment: I tried doing that but the same thing happens

Comment: If you don't see the output of your `print()` statement, then the problem is with your `if` statement.